# JBTable ColumnInfo with button

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jtable, intellij-plugin

I have a JBtable and in one of the columns I would like to insert a button.

My attempt was as follows:

```
 private class DeleteColumn extends ColumnInfo<Field, JButton> {

        public DeleteColumn() {
            super("Delete");
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public JButton valueOf(final Field field) {
            final JButton removalButton = new JButton();
            removalButton.setText("-");
            removalButton.addActionListener((e) -> {
                // do something
            });
            return removalButton;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass() {
            return JButton.class;
        }

    }
```

However when this is rendered, it still only displays the .toString() of the JButton. How can I display a button in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write a custom renderer. Please look at:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender

There are also examples you could look at:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableRenderDemoProject/src/components/TableRenderDemo.java

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to insert a button

You should NOT be adding a JButton to the table. The data of the JTable should not be a Swing component. You should just be storing text in the column and then use a JButton to render the text.

For example check out [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for a class that allow you to use a button as the renderer/editor.